# Simplest way to convert 78 VDC to 3.3 VDC?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, esp8266

I'm doing a ESP8266 implant on a LED light driver, which converts 220 VAC to 78 VDC. I need to power the ESP8266 with 3.3 VDC.

What is the smaller, cheaper, easier and efficient way (if any) to do the conversion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much current does the ESP8266 need? Is cheap and easy or efficient more important to you? Because these are conflicting goals.

Comment: There are monolothic switching regulator IC's from Linear Tech that sport wide input range. [This LT8631](http://www.linear.com/product/LT8631) will do up to 100V input for 1-12V output and meant for regulating 3.3/5V  off of automotive/telephony supplies. Its probably the most efficient solution in a single chip.

Comment: TIs LM5018 or LM5017 would also be an option. Both of these parts in their Webench tool, if you stick in your voltage/current requirements it will design the circuit for you.

Comment: @ThePhoton: 215mA

Comment: @TomCarpenter: I thank you very much for your offer, however, I think that this circuit won't fit in the inner of the LED driver. What would be the final size of the (highly optimized) circuit?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://wiki.iteadstudio.com/ESP8266_Serial_WIFI_Module), the ESP8266 can draw up to 215mA when transmitting, so you need about 0.7W supply capability to not have to worry about what the chip is doing.

There are a number of switcher chips (including output transistor) that will work with ~100VDC input. The LM5018 is one such possibility (I've used its lower-current little brother the LM5019). You could roll your own using an offline switcher circuit with internal or external switch- provided the ULVO does not cause problems.

Another possibility (especially if parts cost is the most important concern) is to make a linear pre-regulator and use a lower voltage switch regulator. For example, if you used a MC34063 with an input voltage of 35V you would have to drop 43 volts at about 20mA, or about 0.9W when transmitting (and much less when not). The linear preregulator could be as simple as a zener diode, a resistor and a BJT.

For much lower currents, and thus probably not suitable here, one very elegant approach that could work might be to put a shunt regulator in series with the LEDs. The maximum current you could draw would be the LED string current. So if the LEDs drew 300mA the shunt regulator would dissipate about 1W with the ESP8266 chip in standby. However it would stop working when the LEDs were turned off, which I suspect would not be useful.

Comment: Note that the [ESP8266](https://www.adafruit.com/images/product-files/2471/0A-ESP8266__Datasheet__EN_v4.3.pdf) weighs in at an average of 120-170mA for TX depending on mode. So a large-ish series of bypass capacitors might be possible with lower overall current demand than 215mA. But this is "walking the line" in terms of reliability.

Comment: @rtdsc Yes, it would be especially bad if there was a latch-up state where the transmitting could drag the supply down so it wasn't working well enough to get out of that state. Even a somewhat unsustainable amount of power dissipation is not that bad.

Answer (score 2):

I've been waiting for someone to ask this question since I read [Microchip App Note AN954](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00954A.pdf) on Transformerless Power Supplies back in 2004! :)

First off, you do not get to pick the smallest, cheapest, easiest *and* most  efficient because all of these are conflicting constraints. Don't be greedy. What I will present, however, is almost certainly the smallest, cheapest, and easiest way. And let's get real, we are talking about a mains tied power supply - who gives a crap about efficiency? :)

So throw away your transformers, linear regulators, and buck converters... all we need is a sticking diode and a humble resistor!...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1hjrT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The [zener diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode) D1 will [start conducting to ground anytime its voltage is above 3.3 volts](http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/ds18004.pdf). Resistor R1 will drop the voltage coming from V1 based on how much current is going though it as per V=IR. As long as (1) we do not exceed the current rating on D1, and (2) the voltage drop across R1 is less than (78-3.3) volts when the ESP is drawing maximum power, then it should work!

The ESP8266 draws between [0 and 250mA](http://wiki.iteadstudio.com/ESP8266_Serial_WIFI_Module).

When the ESP is drawing 0mA, there will be [~300mA](https://www.google.com/search?q=(78%20volts%20-%203.3%20volts)%20%2F%20250%20ohms&oq=(78%20volts%20-%203.3%20volts)%20%2F%20250%20ohms&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.12394j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) flowing though the diode, so make sure you pick a zener that is rated for at least [1 watt](https://www.google.com/search?q=300mA+*+3.3+volts&oq=300mA+*+3.3+volts&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.3573j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

When the ESP is drawing 250mA, then there will still be about [~15 volts](https://www.google.com/search?q=78%20volts%20-%20(250mA%20*%20250%20ohms)&oq=78%20volts%20-%20(250mA%20*%20250%20ohms)&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.23111j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#) available before the diode, so there will be adequate voltage to drive the ESP. Note that if we had chosen a 300 ohm R1, then the ESP would [not get enough voltage](https://www.google.com/search?q=78%20volts%20-%20(250mA%20*%20250%20ohms)&oq=78%20volts%20-%20(250mA%20*%20250%20ohms)&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.23111j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=78%20volts%20-%20(250mA%20*%20300%20ohms)) when it tried to draw 250mA.

There are [lots of 3.3 volt zeners that can handle 1 watt on Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv920=505&pv920=787&pv588=7&pv588=1099&pv588=106&pv588=1645&pv588=105&pv588=427&pv588=8&pv588=237&FV=fff40015%2Cfff8030a&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) and they are very cheap.

As @TomCarpenter correctly points out, you will need a honking 20 watt resistor for R1.

Comment: Sure, you only need an 19W rated resistor... plus you get an efficiency of a massive 4%.

Comment: @TomCarpenter No argument here! :)

Comment: The 3V3 Zener has tolerances that will make things borderline to get your 3V3 rail within spec.Low voltage Zeners are much more spongey  than higher voltage types .This dynamic resistance will push your 3V3 out of spec .If you dont do something about this you will have a production disaster.What I did was use a 5V1 and a low drop linear reg .You could use a better shunt reg .The 3V3 Zeners have not got better over the decades .They were invented well before 3V3 logic.

Comment: @bigjosh: This seems a good solution for a simulator, but, if I'm rejecting the buck converter idea because it's too big... What about adding a 20W resistor to my project? **;-)**

Comment: @Helio so now you are going to pile on "practical" to your list of constraints? :) In all seriousness, this could become a practical design if you can cooperate on the software side. The ESP only draws maximum power when transmitting. If you are careful to only transmit briefly and rarely, you can bring the average current draw down low enough that you could use a practical dropping resistor, along with potentially a buffering cap and a switching diode on the ESP.

Comment: Depending on your application, you may be able to get away with not transmitting at all. If you only want to be able to control the lights over wifi, you could configure the interface to be listen only and use broadcast or mulitcast UDP packets to control the lights. No ACK on the network necessary since you know the message got though by looking at the lights.